# Matrix of a linear map in a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am working on basis in my Linear Algebra class and I got this example where I am searching the matrix of a linear map. I am a bit confused about this notion : **could you explain it to me ?**

Let f : $\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R^2}$  be the linear map such that $f(1,0) = (0,1)$ and $f(0,1) = (1,1) $

The matrix of $f$ in the basis $(1,1) ; (0,1)$ is : \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: How did you define the matrix of a linear map with respect to a basis?

Comment: Write $f(e_i) = a_ie_1 + b_ie_2$, then $(a_i,b_i)^T$ is your $i$-th column in the matrix.

Comment: You might find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1525600/81360) to be helpful

Comment: I found the answer, I will write it here. Might be useful to someone. Thank you !